# How do I add image upload to an existing form?

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms

I have a form I'm building that uploads the form content into a database (mysql) and a separate page to display the contents of the database. So far everything works great. I need the users to be able to upload an image file along with the form and I need the image itself to display on the page with the database contents.

How do I accomplish this by modifying the existing code? I've included the form code, the code that posts to the database and the page code that displays the content below.

Thank you!!

Form:

```
<form name="sponsor-registration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"        action="sponsor-registration.php">
 <div class="formcentered">
 <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="yourname" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Your Name:</div>
 <br class="clearfloat" />
 <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Email:</div>
 <br class="clearfloat" />
 <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="phone" size="30" maxlength="20" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Phone</div>
 <br class="clearfloat" />
 <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="sponsorname" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Sponsor Name:</div>
 <br class="clearfloat" />
 <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="sponsorshiplevel" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Sponsorship Level:   </div>
 <br class="clearfloat" />
 <p class="pagecentered"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  </p>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Posts to the database:

```
<?php //start php tag
//include connect.php page for database connection
include('connect.php');
//if submit is not blanked i.e. it is clicked.
{
$sql="insert into      sponsors2015(yourname,email,phone,sponsorname,sponsorshiplevel,logofile) values('".$_REQUEST['yourname']."', '".$_REQUEST['email']."', '".$_REQUEST['phone']."', '".$_REQUEST['sponsorname']."', '".$_REQUEST['sponsorshiplevel']."')";


$res=mysql_query($sql);
if($res)



{
Echo header('Location: sponsor-registration-success.php');
}
Else
{
Echo header('Location: sponsor-registration-problem.php');
}

}

?>
```

Displays the contents of the database

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, yourname, email, phone, sponsorname, sponsorshiplevel,    logofile FROM sponsors2015";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. "<br>". " Name: " . $row["yourname"]. "<br>". "  Email: " . $row["email"]. "<br>". " Phone: " . $row["phone"]. "<br>". "Sponsor Name: " . $row["sponsorname"]. "<br>". "Sponsorship Level: " . $row["sponsorshiplevel"]. "<br>". "<hr>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This seems like something you can Google, there are many tutorials on the web on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add an image,you need a file input tag

After this,you would need to process the file as below `<input type="file" name="profilepic" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png" />`

```
 <?php function imagEupload()
{
global $picerror;

if ($_FILES['profilepic']['error'] == 4) {
    $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'>No picture was uploaded,kindly upload one.</p>";
}

if ($_FILES['profilepic']['error'] >= 1) {
    $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'> There was an error processing your image," . $_FILES['profilepic']['name'];
} else {
    $validfiletype = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']; // starts an array to hold the valid file extensions.
    $max_file_size = 1024 * 3072; // 3Mb
    $uploadpath = "uploads/";
    $uploadedfilename = $_FILES['profilepic']['name'];

    if ($_FILES['profilepic']['size'] > $max_file_size) {
        $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'>The uploaded file," . " $uploadedfilename" . " is too large</p>";
    } else {
//            get the file extension and check it to make sure it tallies with the valid extensions set in the array

        if (!in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['profilepic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $validfiletype)) {
            $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'> The uploaded file," . " $uploadedfilename" . " is not a valid image</p>";
        } else {

            $fileext = pathinfo($_FILES['profilepic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = uniqid($_FILES['profilename']['name']) . ".$fileext";


            if (file_exists($uploadpath . $filename)) {
                $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'>The uploaded File," . " $uploadedfilename" . " exists,please upload another or do consider renaming it.</p>";
            } else {
                $filepath = $uploadpath . $filename;
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {

                    global $newfilepath;

                    $newfilepath = $filepath; // input this to your database, to echo the image, it would be something like this <img src='<?php echo $_row['image'] ;' />

                } else {
                    $picerror[] = "<p class='formerrors'>We could not process your image due to an unavoidable error,Please contact us or try again</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

you can also refer to the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

and by the way, the mysql extension is deprecated,do consider using mysqli or PDO , the `header('location') ;` works without `echo` ..I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much!! I've already started playing around with your example and will adapt to my needs. Always grateful for the fast response and knowledge of everyone!

Comment: Thank you! I still consider myself a newbie when it comes to PHP and I'm very much a beginner with databases. Trying to learn all the time and I seem to learn best by getting my hands dirty ... that is, working with code and learning how it reacts to changes (along with good tutorials I can find).